# Built-in module to calculate the least common multiple

Tags: python

I am currently using a function that accepts two numbers and uses a loop to find the least common multiple of those numbers,

```
def lcm(x, y):
   """This function takes two
   integers and returns the L.C.M."""

   # Choose the greater number
   if x > y:
       greater = x
   else:
       greater = y

   while(True):
       if((greater % x == 0) and (greater % y == 0)):
           lcm = greater
           break
       greater += 1

   return lcm
```

Is there a built-in module in Python that does it instead of writing a custom function?

Answer (score 113, accepted):

#### In Python 3.8 and earlier

There is no such thing built into the stdlib.

However, there is a [Greatest Common Divisor](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) function in the `math` library. (For Python 3.4 or 2.7, it's buried in `fractions` instead.) And writing an LCM on top of a GCD is pretty trivial:

```
def lcm(a, b):
    return abs(a*b) // math.gcd(a, b)
```

Or, if you're using NumPy, it's come with an [`lcm`](https://www.numpy.org/devdocs/reference/generated/numpy.lcm.html) function for quite some time now.

Comment: Since Py3.9 there is now [math.lcm()](https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/math.html#math.lcm)

Comment: The subject of [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/402931/whats-the-ettiquette-on-updating-an-accepted-answer?cb=1).

Answer (score 92):

#### In Python 3.9+

This is available as [`math.lcm()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm). It also takes any number of arguments, allowing you to find the lowest common multiple of more than 2 integers.

For example:

```py
>>> from math import lcm
>>> lcm(2, 5, 7)
70
```

Answer (score 16):

Try this instead:

```
def lcm(x, y):
    from fractions import gcd # or can import gcd from `math` in Python 3
    return x * y // gcd(x, y)
```

Comment: Why do you put the import in the function?

Comment: Why not?  It's better to post a self-contained solution than to _assume_ the user is fine with littering a containing scope with names (like "gcd") that are irrelevant to solving the problem at hand.  If _you_ want to move the import to a containing scope, that's fine.

Comment: There is one disadvantage on having imports inside functions: Any missing module will only be discovered when such function is executed. Having all imports unconditionally at the top of a module makes sure all dependencies are available by the time the module is loaded. (Sure, this is not an issue for standard lib modules.)

Comment: ^^ Also, the import time might be expensive. It's generally advisable to pay the cost at module import time rather than function call.

Comment: @TimPeters I've understood that the module level `__all__` is intended to advertise public names, and some extra names in containing scopes doesn't really harm anything. As for "why not", the style guide does say *Imports are always put at the top of the file* but I think the more important reason is for code to be up-front about their dependencies. That makes browsing a large code-base easier, and during testing it means mocking/patching a dependency from the module namespace is simpler.

Answer (score 2):

To simplify your code a little:

```
def lcm(x, y):
    for currentPossibleLCM in range(max(x,y), (x*y)+1)
         if((currentPossibleLCM % x == 0) and (currentPossibleLCM % y == 0)):
              return currentPossibleLCM
```

Runtime: O(x*y)

Answer (score 1):

This is not only for two numbers specifically but for finding LCM of an array of integers. (without using math.lcm())

```
import math
from functools import reduce

def lcm(arr):

    l=reduce(lambda x,y:(x*y)//math.gcd(x,y),arr)
    return l
```

Answer (score 0):

I've created this one for receiving an arbitrary number of parameters and thus calculate the lcm

```
from math import gcd, prod

def lcm(*list):
    return abs(prod(list)) // gcd(*list)

lcm(1,44,22)
```