# find if integer i is divisible by all elements in a list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, math

as the title states, I want to find if integer `i` is divisible by all elements in a list.

I have this:

```
db = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
i = 1
if all(i % d != 0 for d in db):
  i += 1
```

I tried using an `if` loop with `all()`, but it just skipped over that section even though the condition is met (I think). It should just add to the integer `i` until it is divisible by 3, 4, 5, 6, 7,and 8.

Any tips or anything I'm doing wrong?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: What output are you expecting? It's a bit vague.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [built-in module to calculate least common multiple](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716916/built-in-module-to-calculate-least-common-multiple)

Answer (score 6):

You checked the opposite:

If it's true for every element of `db` does *not* divide `i`.

You need to switch the branches of your `if` logic:

```
if all(i % d == 0 for d in db):
    print(i, "is divisible by all elements of the list")
else:
    i += 1
```

Alternately:

```
if any(i % d != 0 for d in db):
    i += 1
else:
    print(...)
```

---

Note that this appears to look for the *lowest* integer divisible by every integer in `db`.  You can do this a lot faster by more directly finding the LCM (least common multiple) of the list.  Put that into your browser's search bar.

Comment: Nice edit, I was just about to suggest utilizing LCM as a tool instead, because it would provide a much faster solution.

Comment: @SunnyPatel yeah I agree lcm is the best way to go about it. I actually already wrote it that way, I wanted to try to approach it from this angle and I ran across this so I thought I'd just use this as an opportunity to learn something new.

Answer (score 1):

`if` is not a loop. It looks like you meant to use `while`.

As well, you have the logic reversed. Use `any` instead of `all`.

```
db = [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
i = 1
while any(i % d != 0 for d in db):
  i += 1

print(i)  # -> 840
```

*(I left out some info that [Prune](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4785185/prune) already covered in [their answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59567088/4518341).)*