# math.lcm() gives error "Module 'math' has no 'lcm' member"

Tags: python, math, visual-studio-code

I was making a simple calculator:

```
import math

number1 = input("Enter a number: ")
number2 = input("Enter a number: ")

result = math.lcm(int(number1), int(number2))

print(result)
```

when I got the error in the title. This works in the shell and even code as simple as

```
import math
math.lcm(10, 20)
```

gives me the error.

Comment: See also: [this older question asking about `lcm` in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51716916/built-in-module-to-calculate-the-least-common-multiple)

Comment: Any chance you've defined your own module `math` that is taking precedence over the standard one?  Search for `math.py`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, let's take a look at the documentation for `math.lcm` to see why it sometimes exists and sometimes doesn't exist!

- [The Doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.lcm)

What's it says? *New in version 3.9.*

Looks like your code works when run with python 3.9, and doesn't work when run with python 3.8 or older.

### Quick fix, python 3.5 to 3.8

On the other hand, [`math.gcd`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/math.html#math.gcd) exists since version 3.5. If you need an `lcm` function in python 3.5, 3.6, 3.7 or 3.8, you can write it this way:

```py
import math

def lcm(a,b):
  return (a * b) // math.gcd(a,b)
```

### Quick fix, python < 3.5

So `lcm` is in `math` since 3.9, and `gcd` is in `math` since 3.5. What if your python version is even older than that?

[In older versions, `gcd` wasn't in `math`, but it was in `fractions`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/fractions.html#fractions.gcd). So this should work:

```py
import fractions

def lcm(a,b):
  return (a * b) // fractions.gcd(a,b)
```

### Which python version am I using?

Please let me refer you to the kind user who asked that exact question:

- StackOverflow: [How do I check what version of Python is running my script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1093322/how-do-i-check-what-version-of-python-is-running-my-script)
- [Using the python 3.9 interpreter in Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment) [*thanks to user:Jill Cheng for this link*]

Comment: @pepo_boyii Please read the text I wrote in my answer and not just the code.

Comment: @pepo_boyii You had trouble with `math.lcm` because it only exists since 3.9. One of the two pythons versions you're using is too old and doesn't have `math.lcm`. Now you have trouble with `math.gcd`. This function exists since python 3.5. I am guessing you are using a python version older than 3.5.

Comment: My interpreter shows I'm using 3.9. Maybe there's something wrong with the interpreter?

Comment: @pepo_boyii print the Python version *in the script you're running* to make sure you don't have different versions installed on your system.

Comment: @MarkRansom still gives me 3.9.0 :/ Something is obviously wrong here but I just can't find what it is

Comment: @pepo_boyii -As Stef said, "math.lcm()" is a new function supported by Python3.9. It is recommended that you use this function when using the Python3.9 [interpreter](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments#_select-and-activate-an-environment).

Answer (score 0):

lcm() can have more than two arguments, like in Python 3.9+:

```
from math import gcd

#def lcm(a,b):
#    return (a * b) // gcd(a, b)

def lcm(*integers):
    a = integers[0]
    for b in integers[1:]:
        a = (a * b) // gcd (a, b)
    return a
```